# Usage of commas in the English language

Tags: punctuation

English is not my mother tongue, and I have a question regarding commas.
In many languages grammar and punctuation rules are fixed, not using a rule is a mistake.
My impression is that in English punctuation rules are used only if otherwise the meaning is unclear.
For instance: "You will be late Mike." Before the vocative case, you need a comma, it should be: "You will be late, Mike." but the sentence is clear even without it.
So, is a comma necessary? Must commas be used if the meaning is clear anyway?

Comment: [English punctuation](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/IELL-Punctuation.pdf) is largely a work in progress that's never been effective. Most English speakers don't know what rules there are, and rarely follow them even if they do. Which is good, because most of the rules are wrong. The problem with commas is that they can be used to represent intonation curves in speech, but most people think of them as grammar instead of pronunciation and get lost. Really good writers can hear them, and use them effectively, but most don't.

Comment: True, "You will be late Mike" is clear without the comma and so is **You will be late Mike**

Comment: Yes, we have to live with it. Punctuation in English has some rules that are largely binding (using a comma to offset a vocative in most sentences [the modern use of 'vocative' in English studies refers not to a case but  to a parenthetical address within running text, as in "Lets eat, Sam!") _Most_ sentences? Yes, there are grey areas even here, as with _Hey Jude_. Comma positioning **usually** corresponds to where one would insert a slight pause in enunciating a string. So not considered essential before direct speech. But look up other questions on ELU for more details.